# Adding buttons to available list in TToolBar customize

Tags: delphi, toolbar, c++builder

`TToolBar` has a property called `Customizable` which when set to true enables customize editor - by double-clicking `TToolBar` (which opens ToolBar Customize window).

I have some issues with that window:

How can I add buttons to list on the left (available buttons), tried modifying properties of already added buttons but haven't found property that may control this. [MSDN explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I need to add buttons myself but doesn't specify how.

Comment: I'd like to answer the question, but you asked three different questions. I'd like to try and answer the first bullet point. But I won't if there are two other questions.

Comment: the article you linked explains first point, I don't think you can change the size of the window or add additional components. You would probably be best to exclude the whole dialog in the first place and replace it with your custom built one and then simply handle the appropriate messages as described in the article.

Comment: @PeterVonča Whilst the article explains how to do it from the Win32 perspective, it's not how to do it from a VCL perspective.

Comment: AFAICT, the answer to the 3rd question is the same with the answer to the 2nd question. The customization dialog does not natively support "text options" and "icon options" combos. The picture with these two elements previously in MSDN documentation have been substituted with a picture without these elements, as can be seen from the link in the question. The dialog resource in 'comctl32.dll' ('comctl32.dll.mui' in newer OS) does not have these combos since as far back as W2K (can't check 9x).

Comment: That leaves the only answerable (without hacks) question to be the first bullet point which I think is realized in 'OnCustomizeNewButton', but the code seems to be doing a lot of button tracking.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, `OnCustomizeNewButton` is the answer to Q1. I'd like to write about that.....

Comment: @David - I hope the question is edited, your answer would be valuable for those who'd like to use native toolbars.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Well, I'm not sure that there'd be much value. All I would do is point the user at the `OnCustomizeXXX` events and link to http://users.skynet.be/oleole/Internet_Explorer_UI.htm

Comment: @David - Then I think you've already answered the question :)

Comment: Please answer only first bullet, that is more than OK, this is the most important one anyway and I can live without second two but I do require to add items on the left. I've removed other bullets. I guess you've already answered in the comments (`OnCustomizeNewButton` event) but may be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to populate the available buttons of the dialog is to handle the [`OnCustomizeNewButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.OnCustomizeNewButton) event. In fact in general, the Delphi interface to the toolbar customization facilities is made available through the various `OnCustomizeXXX` events.

I've not found any Embarcadero code sample for customisation. The only Delphi specific resource that I have discovered is this post from Fabio Lucarelli: http://users.skynet.be/oleole/Internet_Explorer_UI.htm

I suggest that you use Fabio's post, the VCL source code, and the MSDN documentation that you linked to in the example. These information sources should be ample to make forward progress.

Comment: Code on that link also shows how to add some more buttons to that dialog (by adding panel and adding dropdowns with that panel as `Parent`). More than enough - thanks!